# cd to most recently modified directory after ls -lt in one command

Tags: bash, ls

When i browse logs, i use `ls -lt` in order to see most recently modified folders. Is there a shortcut for entering this folder in one command?
Perhaps pipe to other command will do the trick?

For example: `ls -lt` output:

```
1 -folder

2 -folder

3 -folder
```

How i can `cd` to folder 1 without copying and pasting its name?

Comment: Do you insist on this solution? It can be done, of course, but midnight commander (mc) exists for tasks like yours among a zillion.

Comment: I would like to know how it can be done without installing `mc`.

Comment: It is general wisdom that you [should not parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). There are just too many ways it can fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with running `ls` again, you could use a bash function:

```
function cd1()
{
 # cd to most recently modified directory in current path
 local c=$(ls -tF | grep '/$' | head -n 1)
 if [ ! -z "$c" ]; then cd "$c"; fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A much uglier way is creating an alias in which we catch the first directory* line while letting all the lines go to stdout:

```
alias ls-lt='ls -lt | awk --re-interval '\'' {print}; /^d/ && !first {sub( /^([^ ]+ +){8}/, ""); print $0 > "/tmp/first.tmp"; first=$0}'\''; eval cd "$(cat /tmp/first.tmp)"'
```

Here you should use ls-lt instead of ls -lt, seeing the same output and cd-ing at the same time.

- Be aware that if a regular file is created in your main directory, that may be the first element of ls -lt which obviously is not a subject of cd.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shortest command of any of the answers provided so far.  Well, actually, it doesn't answer the actual question, since technically the question is to parse the output of "`ls -lt`".  However, if I assume that the purpose of "`ls -lt`" is to show directories sorted by time, then this answer does accomplish the actually intended goal.

`cd "$( ls -1Ft | grep /$ | head -1 )"`

(Note: The parameters to the "ls" command and the "head" command contains a number, not a lowercase L.)

Edit: I just added quotation marks, because some testing showed that they cause the command to also work if the directory has a space in the directory's name.